# Changing Jenkins build artifacts file ownership

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server building a Maven project. When Jenkins builds this project, all build artifacts under `$WORKSPACE` have file permissions `jenkins:jenkins`.

In a *post step*, these build artifacts shall get copied to `/srv/myproject/`, from where a Tomcat instance serves the built artifacts. `/srv/myproject/` is owned by `tomcat7/tomcat7`.

This post step fails and Jenkins reports `Failed to copy $WORKSPACE/somefile to /srv/myproject/somefile due to java.io.FileNotFoundException /srv/myproject/somefile (Permission denied)` — Linux user `jenkins` is not allowed to modify files owned by Linux user `tomcat7`.

How can I change ownership of Jenkins' build artifacts? I am looking for solutions that take security into mind, e.g. giving `jenkins` sudoer permissions does not seem wise. Also, changing ownership of `srv/myproject/**` to `jenkins:jenkins` feels more like a workaround.

Comment: Could jenkins and tomcat7 both belong to a shared group called something like, ci_build?  I'm not sure that provides any more security than what you've already suggested though (just makes things a bit clearer - "why are the Tomcat files owned by jenkins?").

Comment: How about adding user 'jenkins' in usergroup of 'srv/myproject' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider creating a group for the two users, let's call it `ftp`.

You can change ownership of the `/srv/myproject/` folder to the `ftp` group:

```
sudo chown -R :ftp /srv/myproject
```

Add the users `jenkins` and `tomcat7` to the `ftp` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G ftp jenkins
sudo usermod -a -G ftp tomcat7
```

Now both users `jenkins` and `tomcat7` should be able to access `/srv/myproject`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try archiving (zip, rar, etc.) all the required files with the proper ownership preserved into a file with full permission (e.g. archive.zip file that have 777 permission), so when you'll unarchive it you'll get the correct ownership for the files.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying files to in-service isn't really what Jenkins is for. If this is the best solution for you for now, then you should probably run the deploy script as the tomcat user; that is, use "sudo" or equivalent in your Jenkins shell script.

There are better solutions you should consider.

- Declarative environment configuration using Puppet, Vagrant, Chef, Powershell DSC or any number of alternatives are good if you plan on scaling this out significantly in the future.
- If you're confident that you'll never need more than a few deploys (e.g. shared dev env, acceptance test env, staging x2, production x2, and that's it...) then the Jenkins job should build an installer of some kind (dpkg, yum file, ZIP file, msi...) and a small automatable, repeatable and controllable process can be built around that. It can even be triggered by Jenkins!

Answer (score 0):

If copy must be done as local operation, then using linux user/groups/ACLs already described in comments.

If it possible to not do local copy, then you can enable ssh access for tomcat user and upload artifacts with sftp/rsync with setting right rules. Performance penalty will be not so huge, but you will be able remove local environment lock and have ability to do upload into any env in future.